# Como puedo unir listas

Tags: c#, linq

Soy muy nuevo en esto y tengo una consulta. Yo acá tengo cuatro listas diferentes llamadas cartasOro, cartasCopa, cartasEspada y cartasBasto y lo que estoy intentando es fusionar estas cuatro listas en una sola llamada mazo es decir yo quiero que en esta lista aparezcan los cuarenta strings que van de O1 a BK muchas gracias.

```
var cartasOro = new List<string>() { "O1", "O2", "O3", "O4", "O5", "O6", "O7", "OJ", "OQ", "OK" };
var cartasCopa = new List<string>() { "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "CJ", "CQ", "CK" };
var cartasEspada = new List<string>() { "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "EJ", "EQ", "EK" };
var cartasBasto = new List<string>() { "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "BJ", "BQ", "BK" };
List<string> mazo = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `Union`

```
var cartasOro = new List<string>() { "O1", "O2", "O3", "O4", "O5", "O6", "O7", "OJ", "OQ", "OK" };
var cartasCopa = new List<string>() { "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "CJ", "CQ", "CK" };
var cartasEspada = new List<string>() { "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "EJ", "EQ", "EK" };
var cartasBasto = new List<string>() { "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "BJ", "BQ", "BK" };
var mazo = cartasOro.Union(cartasCopa).Union(cartasEspada).Union(cartasBasto);
```

La función `Union` te entregará un `IEnumerable` el cual no puedes agregar ni eliminar items. Si eso no te sirve puedes convertirlo a `List` usando `ToList`

```
var mazo = cartasOro.Union(cartasCopa).Union(cartasEspada).Union(cartasBasto).ToList();
```

Por otro lado y fuera del tema de la pregunta. Quizas te convenga utilizar una estructura en lugar de un string para las cartas, algo así:

```js
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Carta> Mazo = new();
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        //un entero 'i' puede ser convertido a una enumeración, realizando un "Cast" -> (CartaValor)i
        Mazo.Add(new Carta((CartaValor)i, Palo.Copa));
        Mazo.Add(new Carta((CartaValor)i, Palo.Basto));
        Mazo.Add(new Carta((CartaValor)i, Palo.Oro));
        Mazo.Add(new Carta((CartaValor)i, Palo.Espada));
    }
           
    foreach (var item in Mazo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    //==========================================================================================
    //puedes comparar valores de una enumeración para determinar si es mayor, menor o igual
    Carta oro2 = new(CartaValor.Dos, Palo.Oro);
    Carta orok = new(CartaValor.K, Palo.Oro);
    Console.WriteLine(oro2.valor > orok.valor); //imprime false porque K es mayor que 2


    Carta otro_orok = new(CartaValor.K, Palo.Oro);
    Console.WriteLine(orok == otro_orok); //imprime true, porque Carta es un record y los record comparan los valores de sus propiedades para determinar si son iguales o no

    //==========================================================================================

    //generamos una lista con todos los oros
    List<Carta> Todos_los_oros = Mazo.Where(a=>a.palo == Palo.Oro).ToList();


    //==========================================================================================

    //ordena las cartas por su valor y lo imprime
    foreach (var c in Mazo.OrderBy(a => a.valor))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }

    //ordena las cartas por su palo y valor y lo imprime
    foreach (var c in Mazo.OrderBy(a => a.palo).ThenBy(a=>a.valor))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
    //NOTA: OrderBy entrega una Nueva lista ordenada, NO ordena la original

    //==========================================================================================


}


//Un record es una estructura (similar a las clases) que funciona como un tipo dato
//tendras un objeto que será del tipo Carta
//la diferencia con las clases, es que un record permite comparar 2 objetos por los valores de sus propiedades, en cambio un objeto de una clase es igual solo si comparte el mismo espacio en memoria
public record Carta(CartaValor valor, Palo palo)
{

    //una enumeración es un conjunto de constantes, sirve para dar nombre a valores
    public enum CartaValor
    {
        As=1,Dos,Tres,Cuatro,Cinco,Seis,Siete,J,Q,K
    }
    public enum Palo
    {
        Oro,Copa,Espada,Basto
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias genio solo una cosa porque el código que subiste después creo que me facilitaría mucho mas las cosas que lo que estaba haciendo antes pero realmente no entiendo nada y era para ver si podías poner comentarios aunque parezcan inútiles porque la verdad que empecé hace poco y no se que hacen la mayoría de cosas.

Comment: @Teo Agregue unos comentarios y ejemplos para que veas lo que puedes hacer, espero te sean de utilidad.  Saludos

Answer (score 0):

La manera más fácil es unirlas con un `AddRange`, así:

```
var mazo = new List<string>() {}
mazo.AddRange(cartasOro);
mazo.AddRange(cartasCopa);
mazo.AddRange(cartasEspada);
mazo.AddRange(cartasBasto);
```

Pero, yo soy muy feliz desde que descubrí una librería llamada LINQ (que te dejo por aquí para que te leas si quieres aprender:
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=net-8.0)

Para usar una librería, debes poner arriba del documento: `using System.Linq;` y luego, vas a la pestaña *Proyecto*, *Manage NuGetPackages*, y ahí buscas la librería :)

Comment: No necesitas agregar linq usando nuget. Esta incluida desde c# 3... igual, mas alla de eso, para que queres linq aca?

Comment: Ala no lo sabía, muchas gracias por la info

Answer (score 0):

También puedes usar el **método Concat** de **Linq**:

```
var mazo = cartasOro.Concat(cartasCopa).Concat(cartasEspada).Concat(cartasBasto).ToList();
```

La diferencia entre **Concat** y **Union** es que **Union** elimina los duplicados, mientras que **Concat** concatena las listas sin quitar elementos duplicados.